# Efficiency of different solar panels

Tags: solar-cell, efficiency, series

How can I work out the efficiency of two different solar panels (12V and 24V, and both of different makes i.e. different efficiency each one) connected in series?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compare like with like. Measure the panel sizes to obtain the area of the panel. Place them out in the sun side by side so they are exposed to the same amount of light then measure their power outputs.

[image]

Plot a voltage against current graph with different loads. Start by taking a no load voltage reading (V(open)). The maximum power output of the panel will be when the output voltage is half the open circuit voltage (maximum power transfer theorem). You may have to extrapolate this point on your graph. Find this current (I) and you can calculate the maximum power available from the panel for the amount of light falling onto its surface. (= I x V(open)/2)

Divide this power by the area of the panel to give you a Watts per square metre value.

Repeat with the other panel.

You now have two values that can be compared in terms of each panels conversion efficiency.

However even knowing this you are unlikely to be drawing maximum power from both panels. You could connect them both up and repeat the measurement to obtain a third watts per square metre value for the combination.

Comment: The "maximum power transfer theorem" applies to a voltage source with fixed output resistance. A PV cell is essentially a voltage limited current source so the output voltage at maximum power will be closer to the open-circuit output voltage.

Comment: Maybe one should note that, naturally, all measurements must be done *concurrently* when using the sun as reference source of light, which changes sometimes considerably within seconds. - Often the naked eye will not even notice the difference in brightness over a broad range; conservatively from own experience I'd say that at least +/-25% in absolute brightness will usually go absolutely unnoticed, while the solar panel will react almost linearly to the intensity.

Answer (score 0):

Being in series, they will have the same current, which will be determined by the lowest current of the two. If the nominal current of the panels is very different the efficiency will be very low.

Let's assume that you have two 24 W panels, P1 is 12 V and P2 is 24 V. It will mean that the \$\text{I}_{MPP}\$ current of P1 will be 2 A and the \$\text{I}_{MPP}\$ of P2 will be 1 A. Connected in series they will generate (in optimal conditions) 1 A at 36 V, or 36 W and the overall efficiency will be reduced by 33% (because the total power would be ideally 48 W).